# Qooxdoo Desktop Design Best Practice

Tags: qooxdoo

I would like to know how you are Design your **Qooxdoo** Code.

I don't get the right Architecture which I am satisfied with.

It is hard to encapsulate the View with logic like services.

I hope someone can give me a hint to a Pattern or something to find a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of Qooxdoo's greatest features is a strong OO class system, so really the pattern that you use is up to you - MVC, MVVC, etc are all possible because Qooxdoo's OO system provides you the tools to implement your preferred pattern(s).

One pattern that I find very useful, especially in creating larger apps, is to define custom widgets for editing models; for example, if you have models (aka "Business Objects" etc) for `Customer`, `Invoice`, `InvoiceLine`, and `Address` having a widget for `CustomerEditor`, `InvoiceEditor`, `InvoiceLineEditor`, etc is really useful firstly because it encapsulates the code, but also because it supports **binding**.

Binding is a very powerful feature of Qooxdoo - to see why, let's assume for a moment that each one of your Editor widgets has a property called `value` which is the thing being edited.

In simple binding, your editor can bind properties of the model to the widgets which display and edit those properties, eg `CustomerEditor` bind `value.firstName` and `value.lastName` to a couple of `qx.ui.form.TextField` and automatically changes to the customer's `firstName` or `lastName` will be updated in the two TextField's.  Binding can work the other way around too, so that changes to the TextField are copied back into the model.

There is a controller class called `qx.data.controller.Form` that can simplify making this happen, and optionally incorporate validation of user values and user feedback too.

If you have separate Editor widgets, you can also bind to them - for example, `Customer` could bind `value.address` to an instance of `AddressEditor`, and `InvoiceEditor` could bind the currently selected `InvoiceLine` to `InvoiceLineEditor` etc